# I want to scrape user and location information from Trustpilot reviews

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have a ready code to scrape information from Trustpilot. I'm successfully scraping information on reviews, heading, timestamp and ranking for all pages. I want to also scrape reviewer details and location information.

I have already tried adding consumer info variable and user info variable. But it's not working.
'

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import json
import math
import pandas as pd

def getInfo(url):
    res=requests.get(url)
    soup = bs(res.content, 'lxml')
    data = json.loads(soup.select_one('[type="application/ld+json"]').text.strip()[:-1])[0]
    return data

def addItems(data):
    result = []
    for item in data['review']:

        review = {    
                  'Headline': item['headline'] ,
                  'Ranking': item['reviewRating']['ratingValue'],
                  'Review': item['reviewBody'],
                  'ReviewDate': item['datePublished']
                }

        result.append(review)
    return result

url = 'https://uk.trustpilot.com/review/instagram.com?page={}'
results = []
data = getInfo(url.format(1))
results.append(addItems(data))  
totalReviews = int(data['aggregateRating']['reviewCount'])
reviewsPerPage = len(data['review'])
totalPages = math.ceil(totalReviews/reviewsPerPage)

if totalPages > 1:
    for page in range(2, totalPages + 1):
        data = getInfo(url.format(page))
        results.append(addItems(data)) 

final = [item for result in results for item in result]
df = pd.DataFrame(final)
df.head()
```

'

I want to get user and location information. `Below is the error I get if I add user.`

```
<ipython-input-11-91758e06aa39> in addItems(data)
     17         review = {    
     18                   'Headline': item['headline'] ,
---> 19                   'User': item['user'] ,
     20                   'Ranking': item['reviewRating']['ratingValue'],
     21                   'Review': item['reviewBody'],

KeyError: 'user'
```

Comment: its User(uppercase U) and not user

Comment: what exactly does data['review'] look like? Does it contain "user"? According to the Error it doesn't.

Comment: @Raphael already answered, check my comments.

Comment: I have not added the user and location functions in the code. Its just that if I add a line as mentioned in the error message, I get an error. For ex.  review = {    
                  'Headline': item['headline'] ,
                  'User': item['user'] ,
                  'Location': item['location'],
                  'Ranking': item['reviewRating']['ratingValue'],
                  'Review': item['reviewBody'],
                  'ReviewDate': item['datePublished']
                }

Comment: @min2bro, its not working with 'User' as well.

Comment: @Raphael, review is only containing the review comments. Please find first line output of above code without user and location details. Headline Ranking Review ReviewDate
0 want My account back 2 I’ve been using Instagram for about 5 years no... 2019-08-22T20:15:15Z
1 They can be really cruel at times and support ... 1 They can be really cruel at times because afte... 2019-08-21T23:44:31Z

Comment: I checked the json on the site and found that there is no user attribute. But there is author attribute. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: @Nishant it works perfectly fine for me. check this https://imgur.com/NwxtOnj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

item dictionary doesn't contain `user` key, it has 
`'author': {
        '@type': 'Person',
        'name': 'Mike Crocker',
        'url': 'https://uk.trustpilot.com/users/5d5ef7c9e427cd04ec0804db',
        'image': 'https://user-images.trustpilot.com/5d5ef7c9e427cd04ec0804db/73x73.png'
      }`, so change your `addItems(data)` function if you want to get user location.

**Ex.**

```
def addItems(data):
    result = []
    for item in data['review']:
        user_location = None
        url = item['author']['url']
        try:
            user_location = bs(requests.get(url).content, "lxml").find('div',\
                    {'class':'user-summary-overview'}).find("div",\ 
                    {'class':'user-summary-location'}).text.strip()
        except Exception as e:
            pass
        review = {
                  'Headline': item['headline'] ,
                  'Ranking': item['reviewRating']['ratingValue'],
                  'Review': item['reviewBody'],
                  'ReviewDate': item['datePublished'],
                   'User' : item['author']['name'],
                   'Location' : user_location
                }
        result.append(review)
    return result
```

Comment: please check the Question it contains the user key as well

Comment: the same code works exactly fine for me, check this imgur.com/NwxtOnj

Comment: @min2bro See OP error  label `Below is the error I get if I add user.` and error message

Comment: your solution looks optimal at this point. there is no user key in review dict and the alternative to user is author > name. Thanks

Comment: @min2bro Can we remove all comment, which is not related to question.

Comment: I agree with @min2bro, I think it will be good to have user ID or any unique value for identification

Comment: Is this code still working for anyone? Doesn't work for me